# Auto Layout is preventing me from changing a view's center

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

One feature of my app is something that does automatic cropping of an image.

The basic idea is that someone would take a picture of a piece of paper (think: receipt), and then the image could get cropped automatically, after the borders of the paper are determined.

I'm able to determine the paper's border by using OpenCV. So, the next thing I do is to change the "center" property of each of my guides (just 2 horizontal and 2 vertical "lines" that can get dragged around manually).

Then, sometime shortly after I make all my calls to change each of the 4 guides, something else comes along and sets the "center" again. (I've overridden "setCenter" to prove this).  The center seems to be reset by this: **[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues]**.

I can't figure out why this is happening, or how to stop it, but it probably has to do with constraints. My view is a simple UIButton. When the user taps & drags on it with their finger, an action routine gets called that just changes the center. This works.

But in another case, I'm bringing up a UIImagePickerController. After they choose the picture, I determine the paper-bounds, change the "guides" centers, and then later on "_applyISEngineLayoutValues" sets them all back.

Any idea what's going on in this case? Or how I can set the center of a view, and have it actually stay?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar thing; I'm setting a view's frame to one with a non-zero size, but then _applyISEngineLayoutValues sets the bounds to be zero.

Comment: Can you show some code. Are you trying to change the CGPoint with... `someView.center = somePoint;`? If so you can't do this with AutoLayout. First rule of AutoLayout is that you can't change the `frame` (read `center`) of a view. If you want the `frame` to change then you must update the `constant` values of any related constraints so that the view is moved to where you want it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first rule of AutoLayout is that you can't update the `frame`, `bounds` or `center` of a view directly.

You must update the constraints related to the view so that the constraints update the view.

For instance, you first vertical line will have horizontal constraints something like...

```
1. Leading edge to superview = some value.
2. Width = some value.
```

This is enough (horizontally) to place this line on the screen.

Now, if you want to move this line to the right you can't just change the `center` you must do this...

```
1. Create a property in you view controller like this...

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *verticalLine1LeadingConstraint;
// or if you're coding the constraint...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *verticalLine1LeadingConstraint;

2. Save the constraint in to that property...

// either use IB to CTRL drag the constraint to the property like any other outlet.
// or something like...

self.verticalLine1LeadingConstraint = [NSLayotuConstraint ... // this is the code adding the constraint...

[self.view addConstraint:self.verticalLine1LeadingConstraint];
```

Now you have a property pointing to this constraint.

Now, when you need to "update the center" of the vertical line 1...

```
// Calculate the distance you want the line to be from the edge of the superview and set it on to the constraint...

float distanceFromEdgeOfSuperview = // some calculated value...

self.verticalLine1LeadingConstraint.constant = distanceFromEdgeOfSuperview;

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

This will update the position of the view and you won't get any errors.

Answer (score 3):

You're using auto layout, so Fogmeister's answer is the right one, but not everyone can use auto layout - e.g. people who have to support the iPad 1 - so I'll leave this answer here.

If you need to use a view's frame but the system is adding constraints, then there is a workaround; but it's not pretty.

`_applyISEngineLayoutValues` sets your view's `center` and `bounds`, but doesn't touch `frame`.  If you override `setCenter:` and `setBounds:` to do nothing, and then always use `setFrame:` in your own code, then `_applyISEngineLayoutValues` will leave you alone.

I'm not happy with this approach, but it's the only way I've found so far to stop `_applyISEngineLayoutValues` from pooing all over my layout logic.

Comment: Rule one of AutoLayout, don't update the `frame`, `bounds` or `center` of a view. If you want these to change then update the auto layout constraints related to that view.

Comment: I have to support the iPad 1, so I can't use constraints.  However, on later iOSes some are automatically added; this is the only way I've found to work around that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realise you weren't using AutoLayout as the question title is about using AutoLayout. I can't remove the down vote unless you edit the answer.